# SQL Server 2008, taking database backup for specified date range

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL server database (SQL Server 2008) which has around 120 tables and when I perform a whole database backup, the backup file comes to around 150 GB. Is it possible for me to take a database backup for a specified date range? Say, I want to take a database backup for all the tables (120) starting from January 2015 to May 2015? Please help. Thank you for viewing this post.

Comment: you mean tables **created** in a specific daterange?

Comment: I meant to say that I want to have a full database backup of all the tables which has records for a specific date range (Jan 2015 to May 2015). The tables (120) do not have any timestamp based columns which I can use for pulling those specific records using some SQL script. Is it possible? Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you need this based on row create or  row change time?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 onwards comes with change tracking if enabled on the database. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280358(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: What **EDITION** of SQL (ie Web, Standard or Enterprise), and do you know what a PARTITION function is?  FileGroups might also help - if you plan ahead.  Hint: you might do better on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for your comments. I need to create a backup of the whole database on row create time (date range).

Comment: I am using SQL 2008 Enterprise version and it's SIT environment, so I do not think there is any partition as such

Comment: I do not have change tracking enabled on the database. Any other way?